# jqgrid json not loading data

Tags: json, jqgrid, gson, jsonreader

I tried a lot to make jqgrid work but it does not work, and problem is there is no error or warning, how to find out where i am wrong. The gd setup is like this. It just show the blank grid, i.e no rows in the grid. I think jqgrid is  not able to load the json data. The grid code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#datagrid").jqGrid({
                       url:'jqgrid.htm',
                       dataType:'json',
                       colNames:['Name','Rollno','Year'],
                       colModel:[
                           {name:'Name',width:100,align:'center'},
                           {name:'Rollno',width:100,align:'center'},
                           {name:'Year',width:100,align:'center'}
                       ],
                       jsonReader: {
                        rows: "rows",
                        page: "page",
                        total: "total",
                        records: "records",
                        repeatitems: true,
                        cell: "cell",
                        id: "id"
                        },
                       rowNum:10,
                       rowList:[10,15,20,25,30,45,40],
                       pager:"#navGrid",
                       sortname:'no',
                       sortorder:"asc",
                       viewrecords:true,
                       caption:"Test"
                    });
                    $("#datagrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#navGrid',{edit:true,add:true,del:true});
            });
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
        <table id="datagrid"></table>
        <div id="navGrid"></div>
    </body>
```

response data- I am sending this data as string using gson. The response is

> {"total":6,"page":1,"records":64,"rows":[{"id":1,"cell":["adeeb","1201",1]},{"id":3,"cell":["Adeeb","1202",1]},{"id":4,"cell":["Adeeb","1203",1]},{"id":5,"cell":["Adeeb","1204",1]},{"id":6,"cell":["Adeeb","1205",1]},{"id":7,"cell":["Adeeb","1206",1]},{"id":8,"cell":["Adeeb","1207",1]},{"id":9,"cell":["Adeeb","1208",1]},{"id":10,"cell":["Adeeb","1209",1]},{"id":11,"cell":["Adeeb","1210",1]},{"id":12,"cell":["Adeeb","1211",1]},{"id":13,"cell":["Adeeb","1212",1]},{"id":14,"cell":["Adeeb","1213",1]},{"id":15,"cell":["Adeeb","1214",1]},{"id":16,"cell":["Adeeb","1215",1]},{"id":17,"cell":["Adeeb","1216",1]},{"id":18,"cell":["Adeeb","1217",1]},{"id":19,"cell":["Adeeb","1218",1]},{"id":20,"cell":["Adeeb","1219",1]},{"id":21,"cell":["Adeeb","1220",1]},{"id":22,"cell":["Adeeb","1221",1]},{"id":23,"cell":["Adeeb","1222",1]},{"id":24,"cell":["Adeeb","1223",1]},{"id":25,"cell":["Adeeb","1224",1]},{"id":26,"cell":["Adeeb","1225",1]},{"id":27,"cell":["Adeeb","1226",1]},{"id":28,"cell":["Adeeb","1227",1]},{"id":29,"cell":["Adeeb","1228",1]},{"id":30,"cell":["Adeeb","1229",1]},{"id":31,"cell":["Adeeb","1230",1]},{"id":32,"cell":["Adeeb","1231",1]},{"id":33,"cell":["Adeeb","1232",1]},{"id":34,"cell":["Adeeb","1233",1]},{"id":35,"cell":["Adeeb","1234",1]},{"id":36,"cell":["Adeeb","1235",1]},{"id":37,"cell":["Adeeb","1236",1]},{"id":38,"cell":["Adeeb","1237",1]},{"id":39,"cell":["Adeeb","1238",1]},{"id":40,"cell":["Adeeb","1239",1]},{"id":41,"cell":["Adeeb","1240",1]},{"id":42,"cell":["Adeeb","1241",1]},{"id":43,"cell":["Adeeb","1242",1]},{"id":44,"cell":["Adeeb","1243",1]},{"id":45,"cell":["Adeeb","1244",1]},{"id":46,"cell":["Adeeb","1245",1]},{"id":47,"cell":["Adeeb","1246",1]},{"id":48,"cell":["Adeeb","1247",1]},{"id":49,"cell":["Adeeb","1248",1]},{"id":50,"cell":["Adeeb","1249",1]},{"id":51,"cell":["Adeeb","1250",1]},{"id":52,"cell":["Adeeb","1251",1]},{"id":53,"cell":["Adeeb","1252",1]},{"id":54,"cell":["Adeeb","1253",1]},{"id":55,"cell":["Adeeb","1254",1]},{"id":56,"cell":["Adeeb","1255",1]},{"id":57,"cell":["Adeeb","1256",1]},{"id":58,"cell":["Adeeb","1257",1]},{"id":59,"cell":["Adeeb","1258",1]},{"id":60,"cell":["Adeeb","1259",1]},{"id":61,"cell":["Adeeb","1260",1]},{"id":62,"cell":["Adeeb","1261",1]},{"id":63,"cell":["Adeeb","1262",1]},{"id":64,"cell":["Adeeb","1263",1]},{"id":65,"cell":["Adeeb","1264",1]}]}

What i am missing more?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You main error is usage of wrong case in [the option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions)

```js
dataType:'json'
```

instead of

```js
datatype:'json'
```

I would recommend you additionally remove `jsonReader` with default values and change `sortname:'no'` to some correct value (`sortname: 'Rollno'` for example). Additionally I would recommend you to use `gridview: true` option to improve performance, `autoencode: true` to be sure that you can display any text in the grid, use `height: "auto"` to have optimal height of the grid. Additionally it seems to me that you should include `loadonce: true` in the grid because the server returns *all data* instead of just one requested page with only 10 rows.

As the result you will have the grid like on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user2003821.htm).

Comment: hey thanks a lot, the problem was dataType. but my pagination is not working, how can i achieve

Comment: @user2003821: Either you should implement pagination in your server code and returns only the requested page or you should add `loadonce: true` option like I suggested you in my answer.